# Problem when asking for confirmation before deleting

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code

```html
<a href="deletedata.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');location.href=this.href +'?ident=' +SelectedId1; return false;" class='linkStyle'> Delete</a>
```

It runs  and calls the php file that deletes the selected record but doesn't pass the record ID so it ends up not deleting anything.

If I remove

`return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');`

it works and delete the record I selected on a table, passing the correct ID, but then I don't have the confirmation message to avoid deleting the wrong record.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're returning the return value of `confirm()` and everything after `;` gets ignored. So it just follows the `href` without doing that redirect you're intending to do.

You need to do something like this:

```
confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') && location.href=this.href +'?ident=' +SelectedId1
```

Which will only do redirect if `confirm()` returns truthy value.

Comment: With your changes for some reason it doesn't ask for confirmation before deleting, even having the "confirm" in there, it just goes straight to deletedata.php and also still doesn't send register id to that page

Comment: I'd recommend using <button> instead of <a> and putting URL into the JS code

Comment: I think JS will not follow URL if you return `false` in onclick handler which is why it was working previously